# How to declare NSDAte in a Class And Assign value through Class Object(iphone Development)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have Question related to nsdate declaration.

```
NSDate *sortDate;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSDate *sortDate;
@synthesize sortDate;
sortDate=[NSDate date];
```

I assign NSdate field in my class with above Procedure.I successfully assign value to my NSDATE(sortarray).Whaen when i retrieve its value's App craches with this message.

"malloc double free/non- aligned pointer being freed set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

Give excess bad error.Some time it show,

When i remove NSDATE field from my class.App Run successfully.

Any thing wrong regarding declaration?

Any Solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date instance you get is autoreleased and not owned by you. If you assign directly to the ivar you have to take ownership, e.g.:

```
sortDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
```

It's usually better though to use the declared property, which takes care of that for you:

```
self.sortDate = [NSDate date];
```

Don't forget to relinquish ownership on dealloc, e.g.:

```
self.sortDate = nil;
```

See the [Cocoa memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1) and the [declared properties documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html).